# Does anyone know what effect has been used on the football players in this picture?

Tags: photoshop-effects, effects

Cheers for any help provided, it's appreciated! [image: https://www.instagram.com/p/Bd97spGni6I/?hl=en&taken-by=skysports]

Comment: looks like the raised the contrast

Answer (score 4):

The players are separated from the background to a new layer. The surprisingly black parts in their pants suggest curves manipulation, the curve is made steeper in dark areas. It's an adjustment layer, so the effect is disabled with layer mask on the faces and other places where it disturbs. The adjustment layer must have "only next layer" -switch =ON. The lowest 1/5 of the image is darkened - probably another adjustment layer with different mask.

The background is quite flat, unsharp, partially red, partially greyshade.

Comment: Right nice, I've been playing around with this now and it looks like a winner to me! Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: @TomGreen: welcome to Graphic Design Stack Exchange! As a new user, you probably want to read the [tour] some time. For now, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)